# When is this set a group?

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that for every $i\in\mathbb{N}$ we have a sequence of integers
$$s_i=(n_{i1},n_{i2},n_{i3},\ldots).$$
Consider the following two operations:
$$s_i^{-1}:=(n_{1i},n_{2i},n_{3i},\ldots)$$
and
$$s_is_j:=(n_{i1}+n_{j1},n_{i2}+n_{j2},n_{i3}+n_{j3},\ldots).$$

> **Question:** For what choices of $n_{ij}$ is the set $S=\{s_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ a group with the above operations?

One trivial example is to take $s_i=(0,0,0,\ldots)$ for all $i$. Then, $S$ is the group with one element. Are there other examples? Or can we prove that this is the only example?

---

**Edit 1:** <s>I think I have another example, but it is fairly difficult to explain.</s> **Subedit: The example is wrong since the repeated sum of a row doesn't appear anywhere.** It appears to have to do with some modification of the Fibonacci sequence. The first few elements of the matrix $(n_{ij})_{i,j\in\mathbb{N}}$ are
$$
\begin{matrix}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 3 \\
 0 &-1 & 0 &-1 &-2 &-1 &-3 &-2 &-2 &-1 &-3 &-2 &-3 \\
 0 &-1 & 1 & 0 &-1 & 1 &-2 & 0 & 0 & 2 &-1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 &-1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 3 &-1 & 2 & 2 & 5 & 1 & 4 & 3 \\
 0 &-2 & 1 &-1 &-3 & 0 &-5 &-2 &-2 & 1 &-4 &-1 &-3 \\
 0 &-1 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 5 & 0 & 4 & 4 & 8 & 3 & 7 & 6 \\
 0 &-2 & 2 & 0 &-2 & 2 &-4 & 0 & 0 & 4 &-2 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 &-2 & 2 & 0 &-2 & 2 &-4 & 0 & 0 & 4 &-2 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 &-3 & 1 &-2 &-5 &-1 &-8 &-4 &-4 & 0 &-7 &-3 &-6 \\
 0 &-2 & 3 & 1 &-1 & 4 &-3 & 2 & 2 & 7 & 0 & 5 & 3 \\
 0 &-3 & 2 &-1 &-4 & 1 &-7 &-2 &-2 & 3 &-5 & 0 &-3 \\
 0 &-3 & 3 & 0 &-3 & 3 &-6 & 0 & 0 & 6 &-3 & 3 & 0
\end{matrix}
$$
Basically, I started with $\begin{smallmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}$ and then the rest is uniquely determined. The identity element is $0$. (Yes, there is a repeated row, and it has to be like that.)

**Edit 2:** If $S$ is a group under those operations, then we can show that the identity element is $0$ and $n_{ij}+n_{ji}=0$ for all $i,j$. Indeed, let $e$ be the identity. Then,
$$e=s_is_i^{-1}=(n_{i1}+n_{1i},n_{i2}+n_{2i},\ldots).$$
Also, $s_i=s_ie$ so
$$(n_{i1},n_{i2},\ldots)=(n_{i1}+n_{i1}+n_{1i},n_{i2}+n_{i2}+n_{2i},\ldots)$$
and hence $n_{ij}+n_{ji}=0$ for all $i,j$. In particular, $e=0$.

**Edit 3:** By Edit 2, the question is equivalent to finding an infinite skew-symmetric matrix $(n_{ij})_{i,j\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that the sum of every two rows is again some row of the matrix. Edit 1 is an attempt at such a matrix.

Comment: You can't define inversion **and** a product! The inverse "operation" is uniquely defined by the product operation in a group.

Comment: @5xum The question still makes sense, but is more restrictive. If we find choices of $s_i$ such that $S$ is a group under addition, but the inverse is not the above, then it does not satisfy the requirement of the question.

Comment: The question starts out a bit weirdly. Is the idea that we are given a matrix $(n_{ij})_{i,j\in\Bbb{N}})$, and you ask whether its rows can form a group in such a way that the group operation is the elementwise addition of rows, but we also need to find the inverse elements as the corresponding columns?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes.

Comment: Or, shortly, are the $n_{ij}$ in your first displayed equation to be the same integers as the $n_{ij}$ in the second displayed equation?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes.

Comment: Ok. That makes an interesting question :-)

Comment: "You can't define inversion and a product!" of course you can.  You just can't declare that they *are*  a group inverse and a group product.  The exercise becomes a mater of i)finding an element e, so that es = se = s for all s.  ii) proving it unique not just for all s but for any s iii) proving ss' = s's = e for all s.

Comment: @Jeff  How is the rest uniquely detemined in your Edit1? From 

$$\begin{smallmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}$$ 
I can only determine
$$\begin{smallmatrix}0 & 0 & 0& \\ 0 & 0 & 1 &\\ 0 & -1 & 0&\\ &&&\ddots \end{smallmatrix}$$ 
(with a diagonal of $0$s).

Comment: @miracle173 $s_2+s_3$ should be a row. Put it at $s_4$. Then, use skew-symetricity to extend $s_2$ and $s_3$ by one more number. Etc.

Comment: You still have to add the inverses $s_2^{-1}, s_3^{-1}$ as a row. Afterwards you can go on with the sums $s_2 + s_2, s_2 + s_3, s_3 + s_3$ and adding their inverses. Then go for the next sums and their inverses and so on. This should in fact yield a possibility and by going for another order this should yield another result. The resulting group seems very boring, just the free abelian group generated by $2$ elements? Of course this would need a proof and the question arises if we add an arbitrary line inbetween befor adding sums/inverses, does this still yield a correct result?

Comment: @menag The problem is that adding more rows like that does not necessarily produce a skew-symmetric matrix. It is still very unclear to me if there exist another solution than the trivial one.

Comment: @Jeff but $s_4:=s_1+s_2$ is not compulsory. So you cannot  say that this start 2x3 matrix uniquely defines your continuation.

Answer (score 1):

The analogous condition to the requirement on the inversion map, for matrices, is that $A^{-1}=A^\mathsf{T}$, which in matrix terms, says that the matrix is an orthogonal matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix.

Here we are dealing with a similar concept for sequences. Note that our operation is componentwise addition of sequences, hence we expect that our identity element is the sequence $e=(0,0,...)$ of all zeros. Thus given an arbitrary sequence, $s_i=(n_{i1},n_{i2},n_{i3},\ldots)$, we expect that $s_i^{-1}=(-n_{i1},-n_{i2},-n_{i3},\ldots)$. If we were to list all our sequences vertically, then we have an infinitary array of numbers analogous to a matrix. Here, the inversion map condition is equivalent to the claim that the inverse of the $i$-th row, is the $i$-th column. Which termwise means that $n_{ij}=-n_{ji}$ for every $i$ and $j$ in the naturals. In particular, we see immediately that $n_{ii}=0$ for all $i$. Note that changing the ordering of the indexing of the sequences by the naturals will typically break this condition: meaning that it is not enough for the collection of sequences to be a group w/ the operation, the set must also be indexed in an ordering that is compatible w/ the transposing condition. (This raises the interesting questions of which sets of sequences is this possible for, and for those that it is, how many different orderings work?)

Edit: More accurately, since our operation is analogous to matrix *addition* rather than matrix multiplication, it is analogous to a *Skew-symmetric matrix*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix

Comment: Why the downvote? The second paragraph is a significant restatement and perhaps part of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Conjecture, based on the OP's edit. Needs a proof (or a counterexample ...)

Let $A$ be a square $n \times n$ skew symmetric matrix with zero first row (and column). Augment $A$ by appending columns to the right, one for each sum of two (not necessarily distinct) columns of $A$, to create an $n \times (n+n^2)$ matrix. Reflect and negate that over the main diagonal, then fill in the lower right hand corner using the same summations for each column. The result will be skew symmetric.

If you repeat this construction forever you build an $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} $  skew symmetric matrix whose column space is closed under finite sums.